# How to convert type_info to the real type in C++11?

Tags: c++11

How to convert type_info to the real type in C++11?

I looked at type_info and actually I expected it to contain the type but it doesn't.
It just has operators and name.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to contain. C++ types are not represented by a reflective system that you can query at runtime. Any decisions based on the properties or qualities of types must be made at compile time.

`type_info` is a manifestation of the "runtime type information" of an object, which does include some information about inheritance in addition to what you find in `type_info`. Unfortunately there's no way to access the inheritance hierarchy besides `dynamic_cast` on an actual instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compile-time type (to use for some other type/variable), use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

If you need runtime type information, use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).